# How to use mousePressed to play when clicked once and stop when clicked twice?

Tags: java, audio, processing

I've learnt how to add music to processing, and now I want to be able to play the song when I click once and pause when I click twice.

I understand that I can use `mousePressed` to be able to play the tune when I click once, but I'm unable pause it if I try use a `if` statement.

```
import ddf.minim.analysis.*; 
import ddf.minim.effects.*; 
import ddf.minim.signals.*; 
import ddf.minim.spi.*; 
import ddf.minim.ugens.*;  

Minim minim;  
AudioPlayer player; 
Boolean value = true; 

void setup() {  
  minim = new Minim(this);   
  player = minim.loadFile("deadmau5.mp3");
} 

void draw() { }

void mousePressed() {
  player.pause();
}

//void mouseReleased()
//{
// player.pause();
// player.rewind();
//} 

void mouseClicked() {  
   if (value == false){   
     player.play(); 
   } 
   if (mousePressed == '2') {    
      value = false;    
      player.pause(); 
   } 
}
```

I tried adding a boolean too but that didn't work either. Anyone got any ideas of what I can do?

Answer (score 1):

Just use a boolean to keep track of which state you're in.

```
boolean playing = false;

void mousePressed(){
   playing = !playing;

   if(playing){
      //play your song
   }
   else{
      //pause your song
   }
}
```

In fact I wouldn't be surprised if minim already had a boolean that kept track of this for you. Something like `player.isPlaying()` or something like that. Might want to check the docs.

Comment: @user3318928 What exactly do you mean when you say it didn't work? Can you post the code you tried? You link `playing` with `player` by simply using `playing` to determine whether you call `player.play()` or `player.pause()`.

Comment: @user3318928 Notice the first line in my `mousePressed()` function: `playing = !playing;` That's what switches the value of the `boolean`, which is what your original code was missing.

Comment: no silly me, I just wrote the code wrong. little mistake of mine lol thank you Sir, that has taught me something.